# What is the difference between these 2 Looping Delete queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, commit, sql-delete

I want to find the difference between doing a delete query in a while loop one with begin transaction and one without.I am trying to delete 200 million rows out of 250 million and keep running something like this in the background. I can't truncate because there is a foreign key in the table.

This is for SQL Server 2012. I tried the one without the word begin transaction and commit transaction and it works fine but once I put the word begin transaction and commit inside the while loop, the table locks up and then starts to rollback as soon as I stop the Execution on SSMS. Is it better to not use the word begin transaction? What is the difference.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT;

SET @Deleted_Rows = 1;

WHILE @Deleted_Rows > 0

BEGIN

DELETE  TOP (4800) FROM s FROM mytable s
INNER JOIN Controltable f on s.fileid = f.fileid
where f.FileDate < GETDATE()-7

IF @@ROWCOUNT < @Deleted_Rows BREAK

    --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:01';

END
```

vs

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT;

SET @Deleted_Rows = 1;

WHILE @Deleted_Rows > 0

BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE  TOP (4800) FROM s FROM mytable s
INNER JOIN Controltable f on s.fileid = f.fileid
where f.FileDate < GETDATE()-7

IF @@ROWCOUNT < @Deleted_Rows BREAK

    --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:01';
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

I thought it was safer to use the begin transaction and since it's inside the the while loop it would commit every 4800 rows and whenever i stop the execution it would rollback only like 100 rows or something, but instead its rolling back all million rows. When I don't use the commit transaction, and beging transaction, it works fine and doesn't rollback. Just deletes 4800 rows and stops as soon as I hit stop execution in SSMS. What's happening here? Am I missing semi colons?  Is the query wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: SQL Server supports *implicit transactions* meaning that each statement is committed when executed.

Comment: So if I don't use implicit transaction like the top query it doesnt get committed? Then how come when i stop the execution the changes are permanent? The rows are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your commit transaction is after the BREAK.  Therefore, on the last run, your while loop will break, and the last BEGIN TRANSACTION will not have corresponding COMMIT.

Therefore, your script looks as though it will always leave an open transaction.  You will need a separate COMMIT after the while loop for the last loop that gets broken.

Comment: Ah gotcha! Thanks a bunch. I need to put that 'COMMIT' BEFORE the break is what you're saying